# Why did my Grid View disappear after I put search function, select,insert,delete,insert gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am learning Gridview .net and C#

I could edit,delete and also insert.

I added search function, search function is working but when the page open, I do not see the gridview on the page, but only textbox of search and button. After I types some, the search function is completely working.

I would like to see the gridview also when the page opens, plus search box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="txt"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="buttongr" />


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FleetManagementConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Genres] WHERE [GenreID] = @GenreID"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Genres] ([Genre]) VALUES (@Genre)"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Genres] WHERE ([Genre] LIKE '%' + @Genre + '%')"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Genres] SET [Genre] = @Genre WHERE [GenreID] = @GenreID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="GenreID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Genre" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Genre" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="GenreID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="Genre" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="GenreID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="True" Visible ="true"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GenreID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="GenreID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GenreID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GenreID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup="Insert" OnClick="LbInsert_Click" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Genre" SortExpression="Genre">

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtGenre" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Genre") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="Insert" ID="rfvGenre" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required"
                    ControlToValidate="Textbox1" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Genre") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
</asp:GridView>



<asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="Insert" ID="ValidationSummary1" ForeColor="red" runat="server" />
```

I just add this code

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Genres] WHERE ([Genre] LIKE '%' + @Genre + '%')"
 <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="Genre" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
```

Why did my GridView disappear?

Thank you so much

Comment: are you sure you have added your bind grid code on page_load() event ?

Comment: please show the `Page_Load` code and how you are getting the data then binding it.. also read on how to ask a question, earlier you asked a question about this same Template in regards to Inserting yet you never called the Insert command..

Comment: your previously asked question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439973/how-to-insert-the-row-on-the-gridview please try not to ask the same question multiple times in different post try to make sure that your initial question has been answered before compounding into another question which is similar which becomes one big mess...!

Comment: @MethodMan I really do not mean to make an mess, according to your help, I could proceed one step. I really appreciate it. Next step is "select "the row, Do you have any recommendation to how to select row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not passing the default value. Simply add `DefaultValue` attribute in your ControlParameter:-

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" DefaultValue="%%" 
      Name="Genre" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
```

Here, I am passing an `%%` since you have `Like` operator. So by default when the page first loads and the value of textbox will be empty, control parameter will pass this default value which will fetch you all the records.

Comment: @haraman - Yeah, that's by default done by `SQL DataSource` when you use `LIKE` operator. But if we pass `%%` it will fetch all the records.

Comment: You mean pass `DefaultValue="%%"` in ControlParameter and keep both `%` along with `'` on both sides i.e. `'%'` in SqlCommand, are you sure it will work?

Comment: @Kazu - Hey you can accept\upvote the answer if it helped you :)